# XMLHttpRequest to gather JSON data to make into table?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html-table, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning about ajax and I'm not sure why I'm not getting my JSON data isn't being displayed into the html with a table? I'm not getting an console errors. I am getting the objects displayed into the console because I have a console log placed in. Essentially just need to get each presidential info displayed into a table listed by the properties in the header.

The HTML

```
<form>  
    <label for="name">Name:</label> 
    <input id="name" placeholder="President Name" type="text"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="loadPresidents()">Search for Presidents</button>
    <button type="button">Clear</button>

    <div id="presidentialTable"></div>
</form>
```

The JS

```
function loadPresidents() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var data = this.responseText;
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsonResponse["presidents"]);
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute('class', 'history');
        var properties = ['number', 'name', 'birthday', 'took office', 'left office'];
        var capitalize = function(s) {
            return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
        }
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(capitalize(properties[i])));
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
        var tr, row;
        for (var r = 0; r < jsonResponse["presidents"].length; r++) {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            row = data[r];
            for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row[properties[i]]));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        document.getElementById('presidentialTable').appendChild(table);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://schwartzcomputer.com/ICT4570/Resources/USPresidents.json", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you were very close. Just did some minor edits and here is the result:

```
function loadPresidents() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                var data = this.responseText;
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(jsonResponse["presidents"]);
                var table = document.createElement('table');
                table.setAttribute('class', 'history');
                var properties = ['number', 'name', 'date', 'took_office', 'left_office']; // changed this
                var capitalize = function(s) {
                    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
                }
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                    var th = document.createElement('th');
                    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(capitalize(properties[i])));
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                var tr, row;
                console.log("jsonResponse", jsonResponse); // changed this
                for (var r = 0; r < jsonResponse["presidents"].president.length; r++) { // changed this
                    tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    row = jsonResponse["presidents"].president[r]; // changed this
                    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row[properties[i]]));
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                }
                document.getElementById('presidentialTable').appendChild(table);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://schwartzcomputer.com/ICT4570/Resources/USPresidents.json", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

I added some inline comments as `// changed this` I think you will see the differences.

Comment: If there are any unclear points, I can explain in more detail

Comment: also, the OP might want to make a second array containing the column titles, since they different from the object properties that are returned in the JSON.

Comment: @ihpar Just working through what you did, looks like I was missing the underscore for the property titles. The console log is outputting the object and not sure about the second one? In the for loop, you went into nesting of the json, like calling the property of the object? And then added the object access for each array?

Comment: @logan26 The presidents response was in this format {"presidents": {
    "date": "...",
    "president": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "name": "...",
            "date": "...",
            "took_office": "...",
            "left_office": "..",
            ...
        }, ... ] } so, yes you are correct you were just missing underscores. The console.log was just to see what the response was. in for loop, just accessed values of keys in json object. You can access values of keys such as var myObj = {"foo": "bar"}; console.log( myObj["foo"] );

Comment: @ihpar Thank you for your help! Learning slowly but surely.

Comment: @logan26 wish you the best. Here is a more explicit answer (I guess): you can access json objects' values by its keys. There are multiple ways but 2 of them are: let's say the object is `var person = { name : "John", age : 45 }; console.log( person.name ); console.log( person["name"] );` both are OK.